# Extract characters from NSString object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, foundation

How to extract individual characters from a string object in Objective-C ?

**Example:**

```
NSString * fooString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FOOSTRING"];
```

I would like to extract individual characters from string object `fooString` is pointing to. `F , O, O , S, T, R, I, N, G.`

Comment: So you want an array with the characters?

Comment: @dasdom Yes. An array with characters.

Comment: @0x8badf00d How do you know what 'ARC' is trying to do?

Comment: @dasdom I think its obvious from question.

Comment: The statement can be simplified: `NSString * fooString = @"FOOSTRING";

Comment: @CocoaFu you're right. I started asking this question referring to string object. NSString * fooString = @"FOOSTRING"; fooString would then be pointing to string literal. Technically both are same but I had to then change my wording so added that extra stringWithFormat:

Comment: @ARC My comment was general and not directed at your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString * fooString = @"FOOSTRING";
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<fooString.length; i++) {
    [list addObject:[fooString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", list);
```

NSLog output:

```
(
                                                  F,
                                                  O,
                                                  O,
                                                  S,
                                                  T,
                                                  R,
                                                  I,
                                                  N,
                                                  G
                                                  )
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
[fooString cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: You can also use `[fooString UTF8String]` or even `fooString.UTF8String`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `[NSString getCharacters:(unichar array) range:(nsrange)];` you will get an easy to manipulate array.I needed it my self and found it on [this link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-extract-character-from-nsstring.html)